# Changing memory address of a char*

Tags: c, memory-management, syntax

I have the following code:

```
str = "ABCD";  //0x001135F8  
newStr = "EFGH"; //0x008F5740
```

`*str` after realloc at 5th position - `//0x001135FC`
I want it to point to: `0x008F5740`

```
void str_cat(char** str, char* newStr)
{
 int i;
 realloc(*str, strlen(*str) + strlen(newStr) + 1); //*str is now 9 length long
 // I want to change the memory reference value of the 5th char in *str to point to newStr.
 // Is this possible?
 // &((*str) + strlen(*str)) = (char*)&newStr; //This is my problem (I think)
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can change a pointer to point to an arbitrary memory location, but you can't make make one pointer point to two places or non-contiguous blocks of memory just like that.

Comment: I don't want to point to 2 places. I want to point to an non-contiguous block(the 5th place in the char array will point to a different place in memory). This is not possible?

Comment: no, this is not possible. A string in c is a CONTINUOS array of char's terminated by a 0 - There are other string implementations around that itself represent a string (usually a very long string) as a list of strings internally, but that is usually for a special purpose

Comment: No, it's not possible without additional data structures like [ropes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void str_cat( char* dest, char* src )
{
   dest = realloc( dest, strlen( dest ) + strlen( src ) + 1 );

   strcpy( dest + strlen(dest), src );
}
```

should work - although I do not have a compiler at hand to test

or even faster and almost no pointers: http://www.koders.com/c/fid359660C181A42919DCB9E92C1406B7D16F27BB8D.aspx

Comment: You should probably return `dest`.

Comment: yeah, but since the OP did not do it.. But I agree!

Comment: and also some checks for security should be added like calculating the needed memory in a var and then using strncpy ...

Comment: No, that's not what `strncpy` is for.  There is almost never a good reason to use `strncpy` -- it's for zero-padded strings, which are relatively rare.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing something very important about C.  A pointer is just an address in memory.  It's live an address on the street.  Let's say I like at 409 K Street.  Then someone goes and spray paints "D" at 409, "E" at 410, "A" at 411, and "D" at 412.  Then someone goes and spray paints "B" at 202 M Street, and "E" at 203, "E" at 204, "F" at 205.  Does it make any sense that you can just go and say "hey, now 413 K Street is now the same as 202 M street?"  No, it doesn't!  Instead, you have to go find a block with a bunch of houses that haven't been painted yet, and write "DEADBEEF" on eight of them.

By analogy, in C you will allocate a new string, with length of the two strings, plus 1, for the zero terminator, and then copy the first string over into the first four positions, and next string into the remainder.